# "Insecure_redirect_uri" error on my Box App on authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api

I'm try to test my app, and I'm testing it both on localhost and on heroku.

I try to not set a `redirect_uri` in the "OAuth2 Parameters" on my app's edit page, so I thought I will be able to set it dynamically depending of the host name (localhost:port or myapp.heroku.com)

But this doesn't work... Am I doing something wrong?

---

## Edit

Problem should be the protocol for the authentication.

This authentication url request works (but my app on heroku doesn't use https)

```
https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?
  response_type=code&
  client_id=my-client-id&
  redirect_uri=https://myapp.herokuapp.com
```

and this authentication url request doesn't work given me the `Insecure_redirect_uri` error

```
https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?
  response_type=code&
  client_id=my-client-id&
  redirect_uri=http://myapp.herokuapp.com
```

---

PS: note the `redirect_uri` param on both urls.

Answer (score 2):

Box requires all redirect urls to have `https` at the beginning.
The only exception (as far as I know) to this is any url that will point to your local host, i.e, `http://localhost:5000`.

I don't understand why `https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=qwerty&re‌​direct_uri=https://myapp.herokuapp.com` is unacceptable; I use that and it works fine, I just put `'/auth` as my callback url for handling any authentication:

`get '/auth'` for catching the get request with the auth code in the URL query and

`post '/auth` for catching the the tokens in the body of the post

so my redirect URL would read like: `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/auth`

Comment: You right. `https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=qwerty&re‌​direct_uri=https://myapp.herokuapp.com` woks fine, but my heroku app has not https protocol. Maybe problem is exactly the protocol. only localhost woks with http, and the other work only with https.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have https? heroku accepts https, or it should, what framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify one in the OAuth2 configuration, then you either don't send the param, and Box knows where to do the redirect.  Or you have to send that exact one in your redirect_uri param.

If you don't set one in the OAuth2 configuration params on Box's developer console, then you can specify whatever redirect_uri param you want.

Comment: I still have problem... Could problem is because of my test app on heroku use `http` protocol and not `https`?

Comment: To be more clear... This url `https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=qwerty&redirect_uri=https://myapp.herokuapp.com` works (but is not the correct uri) and this one `https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=qwerty&redirect_uri=http://myapp.herokuapp.com` doesn't.